# Why do I keep receiving error with this little piece of code (ode45)

Tags: function, matlab, ode

function dy = g2(x, y)

dy = -0.1 * y;

ym = ode45('g2', 0, 5, 4)

end

I receive the following message:

> g2(0.5,4)
> Error using odearguments (line 83)
> The last entry in tspan must be different from the first entry.

> Error in ode45 (line 115)
> odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options,
> varargin);

> Error in g2 (line 9)
> ym = ode45('g2', 0, 5, 4);

I might add that this one works well:

function dy = g1(x, y)

dy = 3 * x ^ 2;

ym = ode45('g1', 2, 4, 0.5)

end

Comment: The first argument to ode45 should be a function handle, not a string.

Comment: Is this in two different files? If not, you need to close the function definition with an `end`. The time span has also a different interface convention in `ode45`, it needs to be passed as pair of endpoints or list of sample times.

Comment: @LutzLehmann You're right, I missed that. Still, there is no improvement.

Comment: The solver call that uses the ODE function is not part of the ODE function.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, that is the main question. Stackoverflow is not meant for homeworks, but to help in solving issues when the problem is well explained.

Answer (score 2):

I am not understanding what you are trying to do, however I will give you an example.

Usually your functions are defined at the bottom and you call ODE like that :

```
t=linspace(0,7,1000);
initial_value_for_y = 0;
[t,y] = ode45(@myfunction, t, initial_value_for_y);

function dy = myfunction(t, y)
    dy = exp(-t);
end
```

so in the first line we define a vector for time using linspace.
at the second line we set the initial value of our integration
the third line calls ODE45 with a function handle, the time span and an initial value

the rest of the lines are for the definition of your function

**My concern for now is that you question is not clear. Instead of asking "why isn't it working", tell us what you are trying to achieve.**